# How to offline debug augmented reality in Unity?

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I was wondering if there was a way to record the sensor and video data from my iPhone, save it in some way, and then feed it into Unity to test an AR app.

I'd like to see how different algorithms behave on identical input, and that's hard to do when the only way to test is to pick up my phone and wave it around.

Answer (score 0):

What do you can do is capture the image buffer. I've done something similar using ARCore. Not sure if ARKit has a similar implementation. I found this when I did a brief search https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-access-arframe-image-in-unity-arkit.496372/

In ARCore, you can take this image buffer and using [ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG.html) you can create PNG files with the timestamp. You can pull your sensor data in parallel. Depending on what you want, you can write it to a file using a similar approach: https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000341143-How-do-I-read-and-write-data-from-a-text-file-

After which, you can use FFMPEG to convert these PNGs into a video. If you want to try different algorithms, there's a good chance the PNGs alone will be enough. Else you can use a command like so: http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/assembling_video_png_stream_ffmpeg/

You should be able to pass these images and the corresponding sensor data to your algorithm to check.